# Linux lockfile starvation

Tags: shell-script, lock, concurrency

I want to use lockfile functionality for a bash script that will run in parallel. The problem is that in a functionality as in the script below, a starvation can happen in case that the first one to lock is called  immediately again. It seems that `lockfile` is polling with a big enough timeout to allow other processes to acquire the lock.

Is that true? How should that be handled?

```
lockfile test.lock
echo "TESTING $$"
sleep 10
rm test.lock
```

For example:

Two shells :
SH1, SH2 run the script together,
SH1 acquires lock, SH2 is blocked.
PROBLEM:
When SH1 is done and removes the lock, SH2 is still blocked (for about a second...), and if SH1 runs the script in a loop, SH2 will be blocked permanently.

Comment: `lockfile test$$.lock` can help

Comment: How? Cause if the script is run from different sessions, the $$ if different, and the lockfile isn't locking anything... I need the lockfile to be as global as it gets

Comment: It has return as to the beginning. Firstly you should explain your main goal to recive adequate advise.

Comment: The goal is to get mutual exclusion without starvation of a bash script that can be run in parallel from different ssh sessions or different processes, using lockfile.

Comment: From man: "If **lockfile** can't create all the specified files (in the specified order),  it waits  *sleeptime* (***defaults to 8***) seconds and retries the last file that didn't succeed.  You can specify the number  of  retries  (*-r* parameter) to  do  until failure  is  returned." So try to change sleeptime and number of retry.

Comment: You're correct but this doesn't solve the issue. The sleeptime minimum is 1 sec. That's bad for preventing starvation...

Comment: For the SH1' loop can offer to make additional sleep before start again. Re starvation I suppose that 1 sec is not so big delay but you can try decimal amount of sleeptime (for example 0.1)

Comment: Only integer value for sleeptime is valid. And I guess I must add some logic to the lock release and not rely on the `lockfile` only

Comment: You can't sleep a couple of seconds *after* releasing the lock?

Comment: That's part of a logic :). But I was hoping I miss something to make `lockfile` work without any further coding.

Comment: May want to try the [flock](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/flock.1.html) command instead of `lockfile`. It will hang until the lock is available (usig the `flock` system call) rather than polling.

Comment: I think this is what inotify is for. Besides that, though - can you not open a pty for your processes and get them in the same process group with `setsid`? If you can get the one to hang on a read from `/dev/tty` until the other sends an interrupt then this could be easier. You can even tailor the timings yourself down to 20ths of a second with `stty`.

Comment: `flock` does the job.

Answer (score 1):

**You should put the lockfile on a tmpfs, because poking lockfiles will prevent it from sleeping.**

Here are two solutions:

### Static Sleep; Sufficient For a Few Procs

```
WAIT=5  # max seconds between two procs; larger is nicer for the system
lockfile -${WAIT} -r-1 "${LOCKFILE}"

## payload

rm -f "${LOCKFILE}"
# sleep outside the lock for at least $WAIT seconds
#  to give another proc a chance to lock it
sleep ${WAIT}s
```

### Randomized Sleep; Handles Many Procs, But Not Super Nice

```
MAX=5
MIN=3
WAIT=$((MIN+RANDOM/(1+MAX-MIN))) # random sleep between min and max
lockfile -${WAIT} -r-1 "${LOCKFILE}"

## payload

rm -f "${LOCKFILE}"
# sleep outside the lock for at least $WAIT seconds
#  to give another proc a chance to lock it
sleep ${WAIT}s
```

### Longer Waiters Become More Aggressive; Nice For Many Procs

```
MAX=600
MIN=1
WAIT=${MAX}  # max seconds between two procs; larger is nicer
while ! lockfile -r0 "${LOCKFILE}"
do
    sleep ${WAIT}s
    WAIT=$(( WAIT / 2 )) # backoff formula
    if [ ${WAIT} -lt ${MIN} ]; then
        WAIT=${MIN}
    fi
done

## payload

rm -f "${LOCKFILE}"
# reduced WAIT means likely to run again; alternatively use MAX
sleep ${WAIT}s
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure there is a problem.

The [kernel code for fs/locks.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/locks.c?v=2.6.34) contains the following comment:

```
 519 /* Insert waiter into blocker's block list.
 520  * We use a circular list so that processes can be easily woken up in
 521  * the order they blocked. The documentation doesn't require this but
 522  * it seems like the reasonable thing to do.
 523  */
```

If you still do not trust this, the only reasonable alternative is to use semaphores, *semop(2), semget(2)*.